# Error in build for Xamarin Android when adding Google Map

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an android xamarin project, and I only add Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps nuget.

my build has this error :

> error: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist
>         com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback

Comment: Did you add `meta-data` in your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Google APIs , and Google play service, but still I got the error.

I check this path

`obj\Debug\__library_projects__\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps\library_project_imports`

and the folder was empty, this folder suppose to have `.jar` files for Google Map.

So I delete `obj` folder and now everything's working.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

- From the Tools menu, select Open AVD Manager
- From the Tools menu of the Android Virtual Device Manager app, select
  Manage SDK..
- For each of the Android SDK you are targeting, check the "Google
  APIs" checkbox and install the packages.
- You should now have the Google Maps SDK installed.

Comment: There are bunch of Google APIs for each Sdk, should I Insall all of them?